# List and pick canonicals for Python bound vs unbound string method?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Periodically we see Python questions about the difference between bound string methods `s.meth(...)` and unbound methods `str.meth(s, ...)`. These don't get marked as dupes as they are heavy on syntax hence pretty resistant to search. Can we first enumerate them, and then pick canonical targets?

- latest reasking: [Should I use str.something(…) or '…'.something()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940695/str-something-vs-something-in-python)
- 2011: [In Python, what's difference between some_string.lower() and str.lower(some_string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083090/in-python-whats-difference-between-some-string-lower-and-str-lowersome-stri)
- <s>2013: [string.split(text) or text.split() what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/string-splittext-or-text-split-whats-the-difference)
   is actually different; it's about the difference with `string` module</s>
- ...there are [755 questions just on [python] `str.split` alone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+str.split+is%3Aq) which I am wading through categorizing... it's tedious...
- ...many older askings, impervious to search, please list them...
- Related: [Function to check if string is uppercase that is not a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856233/function-to-check-if-string-is-uppercase-that-is-not-a-method)
  OP asks how to write code that takes a string instance as arg, but calls functions, not methods bound to that instance

Comment: Do note that `str.split(x)` is *not* the same as `string.split(x)` the 2013 question is referring to...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: thanks, updated. Folks let me know if you see other askings... they're hard to track down...

Comment: @user2357112: can you cite support for that? [unbound methods were removed from Python 3 in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods)

Comment: @smci: Unbound method objects were removed, but not the concept of bound and unbound methods; unbound methods (or at least the ones implemented in Python) are just represented as ordinary functions now.

Comment: @user2357112: ok but as you mentioned the `__repr__` messages say otherwise, and use the terms "builtin method" vs "method". Does that deserve a bug report?

Comment: Note that the `repr`s saying "method" and "built-in method" already said that on Python 2. Those happen to be how the `repr`s work for two specific types used for specific kinds of methods written in C. Not all unbound or bound methods look like that - not even the ones written in C. (For example, look at `''.__add__` and `str.__add__`, which say "method-wrapper" and "slot-wrapper".) There are like 5 or 6 different types used for bound and unbound methods.

Comment: Wow, i am the OP of the latest question, and i searched, and didn't even see the other questions, now should be a duplicate, but i couldn't find it because i didn't search for a specific function

Comment: @U9-Forward Yes like I said "heavy on syntax hence pretty resistant to search". And the askings reference `lower/upper/split/strip/find/index/count/...` and other methods. It would be great to find other previous askings, pick/create a canonical, then close the dupes in favor of it.